# Are there any ways to increase the precision in MATLAB without built in functions?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, truncation-error, machine-precision, scientific-notation

I am a beginner learning about MATLAB scientific computation, floating point numbers, and numerical error. When I am using a very small $x$ value for some equations, such as $y(x) = (\exp(x)-1-x)/x^2$, the relative error could get very large. To overcome this, I am told to use the built in `vpa` function for better precision. Are there any other ways to increase precision without `vpa`?

Comment: You asked about that function in an earlier post. There several people noted that it is equivalent to $1/2 + $ a rapidly converging power series. That's a way to evaluate it for small $x$  without vpa.

Comment: Well, there are ways to implement [quad precision (128-bit floating point) in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98215-does-matlab-support-quadruple-precision-128-bit-floating-point-arithmetics), but often looking at the underlying mathematics of a given problem, as @EthanBolker points out, is a simpler and more straightforward approach.

Comment: You can always use [mex](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) in combination with one of the available C++ libraries like Boost.Multiprecision to not only get 128 bit floats but 256 bit or even arbitrary high precision (the only real limit is memory and computation time if you want to go extreme).

Comment: Even with vpa you have to figure out how many digits you need for a particular calculation. You can make $x$ very, very small; even with just double-precision input I think you could make $x$ small enough to require over $1000$ bits of precision to do the calculations the way you have shown, whereas by looking at the underlying mathematics you could get the answer with just ordinary floating-point numbers.

Comment: Alternatively you can just use symbolic computation: `x = sym(1e-30); y = (exp(x)-1-x)/x^2; double(y)` gives you the correct result without any need to worry about the number of vpa digits. Without `sym` the result is quite wrong. However, this is also much slower than standard float computations.